# Using Listener with Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, listener

Say I have an Object Foo that wants to get informed by several running instances of a Thread using a listener interface. E.g.

The interface:

```
public interface ThreadListener {
   public void onNewData(String blabla);
}
```

The class Foo:

```
public class Foo implements ThreadListener {
   public Foo() {
      FooThread th1 = new FooThread();
      FooThread th2 = new FooThread();
      ...

      th1.addListener(this);
      th2.addListener(this);
      ...

      th1.start();
      th2.start();
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public void onNewData(String blabla) {
     ...
   }
}
```

The Thread:

```
public FooThread extends Thread {
   private ThreadListener listener = null;

   public void addListener(ThreadListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
   }

   private void informListener() {
      if (listener != null) {
         listener.onNewData("Hello from " + this.getName());
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
     super.run();

     while(true) {
        informListener();
     }
   }
}
```

In the worst case onNewData(..) is invoked by several threads at the same time. What will happen with Foo? Is it going to crash or not?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `Foo`. Is it thread safe? I.e., does the implementation of `Foo` have any data-races?

Comment: Do you want to prevent it? or is it just a theoretical question? onNewData can crash the JVM process (that the kind of crash I know) if for example it piles up in memory all the strings or do excessive memory allocation without de-allocation. Since the method is not thread-safe from outside it can override data written from one thread by the other.

Comment: For the record, your design is all wrong. Don't extend `Thread`. Also, having the listener start threads and add itself to them is a sign of a concern-jungle. Separate the concerns. A listener listens, other code must do the rest.

Comment: ok first, why shouldn't i extend Thread? Second, how would you implement both listener and thread separately as you proposed?

Comment: The Web is full of exlaining why one does not extend Thread. It is a well-known antipattern. One reference is Effective Java by Josh Bloch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Your `Foo` class has no state (fields), so unless it uses external shared resources (e.g. files...) it is thread safe
- Starting thread from a constructor is generally a bad idea although in the case of a state-less object, I suppose it is fine
- if `onNewData` does not access shared data it will work as expected, if it does, the outcome will depend on how the method is implemented.

Comment: @YannickWald http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[java]%20%2bstart%20%2bthread%20%2bconstructor